# How to parse JSON array from inside an object with rapidjson

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson, tiled

The following is a JSON file exported from Tiled Map Editor.

```
{ "compressionlevel":-1,
 "height":32,
 "infinite":false,
 "layers":[
        {
         "data":[ A whole bunch of integers in here],
         "height":32,
         "id":1,
         "name":"Tile Layer 1",
         "opacity":1,
         "type":"tilelayer",
         "visible":true,
         "width":32,
         "x":0,
         "y":0
        }],
 "nextlayerid":2,
 "nextobjectid":1,
 "orientation":"orthogonal",
 "renderorder":"right-down",
 "tiledversion":"1.7.2",
 "tileheight":32,
 "tilesets":[
        {
         "firstgid":1,
         "source":"..\/..\/..\/..\/Desktop\/tileset001.tsx"
        }],
 "tilewidth":32,
 "type":"map",
 "version":"1.6",
 "width":32
}
```

And in this C++ block I am trying to parse out the data I actually need.

```cpp
std::ifstream inFStream(filePath, std::ios::in);
    if(!inFStream.is_open())
    {
        printf("Failed to open map file: &s", filePath);
    }

    rapidjson::IStreamWrapper inFStreamWrapper{inFStream};
    rapidjson::Document doc{};
    doc.ParseStream(inFStreamWrapper);

    _WIDTH = doc["width"].GetInt();   //get width of map in tiles
    _HEIGHT = doc["height"].GetInt(); //get height of map in tiles

    const rapidjson::Value& data = doc["layers"]["data"]; //FAILURE POINT
    assert(data.IsArray());
```

When I compile I am able to extract the right value for width and height which are outside of `"layers" :[{}]`
But when that `const rapidjson::Value& data = doc["layers"]["data"];` gets called I get a runtime error claiming that document.h line 1344 `IsObject()` Assertion Failed.

Ive been up and down the rapidjson website and other resources and cant find anything quite like this.

The next step would be to get the int values stored in "data" and push them into a `std::vector` but thats not going to happen till I figure out how to get access to "data"

Comment: Layers is an array

Comment: Yes, and data is an array inside that array. oh you're talking about the Question title, I said "inside an Object" oops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doc['layers']` is an array.

```
const rapidjson::Value& layers = doc["layers"];
assert(layers.IsArray()); 

for (size_t i=0; i < layers.Size(); i++) {
  const rapidjson::Value& data = doc["layers"][i]["data"];
  assert(data.IsArray());
}
```

UPDATE:

Direct access to first `data` item in `layers`:

```
const rapidjson::Value& data = doc["layers"][0]["data"];
```

This only gives you the `data` for the first item in `layers` array. If `layers` have at least one item and you only need the first one, then this will always work.

Comment: so because Layers is an array I am forced to iterate through is to get to the underlying data, is there no direct way of accessing a nested array?

Comment: You have to point to the item in the array which you're accessing somehow, right?

Comment: this answer works, I nested another for loop below the assert to fill the vector. It appears I was confused as to what Value& was a reference to.

Comment: @AndrewGraham you can always access the first "data" item with `const rapidjson::Value& data = doc["layers"][0]["data"];` where `0` just refers to first element of the layers array - which is fine if you can guarantee layers will always have at least one element in the array, and you only need the first one.

Comment: @mani I was just thinking about that as you posted the comment. I realize now that ```doc["layers"][i]["data"]``` Is just invoking rapidjson's ```FindMember()``` function... Go to layers position "i" and see if there is a member named "data"... Thanks for your help!